# Application Ends when TimerCallback function executes

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I was trying to create a very basic scheduler app in VB.NET (4.0). There is a form and button and label. So what exactly I want to happen is after 10 seconds the label text has to be changed. So here is the stuffs I did.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim t As Timer
    t = New Timer(New TimerCallback(AddressOf timerevent))
    Dim scheduledTime As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
    scheduledTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, 10, DateTime.Now)
    Dim timespan As TimeSpan = scheduledTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now)

    Dim dueTime As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(timespan.TotalMilliseconds)
    t.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite)

End Sub
Private Sub timerevent(e As Object)
    Try
        Label1.Text = Now.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = ex.Message
    End Try

End Sub
```

But the issue is timerevent fires correctly on 10 seconds, but immediately the application stops execution or ends up. I'm not getting an idea why this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `System.Threading.Timer` which will fire the callback in `ThreadPool` thread.

Inside the callback you're updating the UI --which will result in `InvalidOperationException`. Agreed; you have a try/catch which will catch the exception but you again do the same mistake in catch block. Nobody can save you there.

You simply need to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to fix the problem. This will work because the winforms Timer will fire the `Tick` event in UI thread.

[Know the difference between Timers in .Net framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much.. sorry for that mistake... You saved my day!